# Transferring multiple files from one host to another

Tags: python, sockets, mininet

I'm new to python socket programming. I want to transfer 5 files (photos) from one host in mininet to another. The name of these files are numbered respectively (I mean 1.jpg, 2.jpg and ...). The problem is that when I run these codes, the first photo is transferred correctly but others become corrupted. What's the problem:

sender.py

```
import socket
import sys

buf = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.0.0.1',12345))

for i in range(1,6):
    with open("%d.jpg" % (i),'rb') as f:
        data = f.read(buf)
        while 1:
            if not data:
                break
            s.sendall(data)
            data = f.read(buf)
s.close()
```

receiver.py:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('10.0.0.1', 12345))

buf = 1024

s.listen(1)
conn , addr = s.accept()
for i in range(6,11):
    with open("%d.jpg" % (i),'wb') as f:
        while 1:
            data = conn.recv(buf)
            #print(data[:10])
            #print "PACKAGE RECEIVED..."
            f.write(data)
            if not data: break
#conn.close()
#s.close()
```

Comment: your loop does not close the open file. So close it after you exit the while or use `with open(...) as f:` that will close the open file automatically. I asume buffers with data are not flushed in your case

Comment: @hootnot Should I use `f.flush()` when I exit the while? If so I added `f.flush()` when I exit the while but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried f.close() but it didn't solved the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution to your problem is to create a new connection for each file. The code below does that.

#### Sender

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 12345
BUFSIZE = 4096

def send_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        except socket.error as err:
            print(err, HOST, PORT)
            sock.close()
            return

        while True:
            data = f.read(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            while data:
                sent = sock.send(data)
                data = data[sent:]

    sock.close()

fnames = [
    'test0.jpg',
    'test1.jpg',
    'test2.jpg',
    'test3.jpg',
]

def main():
    for fname in fnames:
        send_file(fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Receiver

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 12345
BUFSIZE = 4096
        
def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind failed', err)
        return

    sock.listen(1)
    print('Socket now listening at', HOST, PORT)
    file_number = 0
    try:
        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Connected with', *addr)

            fname = 'image%d.jpg' % file_number
            with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    f.write(data)
            conn.close()
            print(fname, 'saved\n')
            file_number += 1

    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')

    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Break</kbd> (depending on your OS) to exit the receiver.

---

But using those numeric file names at the receiver isn't very satisfactory , so I decided to make it a little more complicated. :) In the following version we send the file name before the file data. That's slightly tricky because the receiver needs to separate the file name from the actual file data. If each `socket.recv` call corresponded to a `socket.send` call that would be easy, but that's not guaranteed to happen: the received bytes may be split differently from how they were sent. The receiver needs to buffer the bytes so it can break them up correctly. See the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) for details.

So that the receiver knows where the file name ends we first send a single byte that encodes the length of the file name. A byte can hold a number from 0 to 255, so this code can't handle file names longer than that. After the length byte, we send the file name itself, encoded using UTF-8. And then we send the actual file contents.

The receiver uses a class named Receiver to handle the buffering. This class has a `.get` method which we can use to get a specified number of bytes. We use that method to get the file name length and the file name. And then we use Receiver's `.save` method to save the received file contents to a new file.

This code is a little bit messy because it's designed to run on Python 2 and Python 3, in any combination. It'd be somewhat neater if it was for Python 3 only. I hard-coded 'localhost' as the host name, since I only have one computer, so I couldn't test it over a network, but I'm confident that it will work correctly on a network.

Here's the sender:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
from struct import pack

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 12345
BUFSIZE = 4096

def send(sock, data):
    while data:
        sent = sock.send(data)
        data = data[sent:]

def send_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        except socket.error as err:
            print(err, HOST, PORT)
            sock.close()
            return

        # Send the file name length & the filename itself in one packet          
        send(sock, pack('B', len(fname)) + fname.encode())
        while True:
            data = f.read(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            send(sock, data)

    sock.close()

fnames = [
    'test1.gif',
    'test2.jpg',
    'test3.png',
    'test4.pdf',
]

def main():
    for fname in fnames:
        send_file(fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here's the receiver:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
from struct import unpack

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 12345
BUFSIZE = 4096

class Receiver:
    ''' Buffer binary data from socket conn '''
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.buff = bytearray()

    def get(self, size):
        ''' Get size bytes from the buffer, reading
            from conn when necessary 
        '''
        while len(self.buff) < size:
            data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            self.buff.extend(data)
        # Extract the desired bytes
        result = self.buff[:size]
        # and remove them from the buffer
        del self.buff[:size]
        return bytes(result)

    def save(self, fname):
        ''' Save the remaining bytes to file fname '''
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            if self.buff:
                f.write(bytes(self.buff))
            while True:
                data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)

def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind failed', err)
        return

    sock.listen(1)
    print('Socket now listening at', HOST, PORT)
    try:
        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Connected with', *addr)
            # Create a buffer for this connection
            receiver = Receiver(conn)
            # Get the length of the file name
            name_size = unpack('B', receiver.get(1))[0] 
            # Get the file name itself
            name = receiver.get(name_size).decode()
            print('name', name)
            # Save the file
            receiver.save(name)
            conn.close()
            print('saved\n')
    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')

    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code is working perfect and your description is complete and very useful. +100 to this answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure, @helen! It was fun to brush up my rusty socket programming skills.

Comment: Dear PM 2Ring, is it possible for the sender to send a simple string like "completed" after sending all of these files and for the receiver to get this message after receiving all 4 files and print it? Although it doesn't seem to be a hard task, I wasn't able to do this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like:

```
   with open("%d.jpg" % (i),'wb') as f:
        while 1:
            data = conn.recv(buf)
            #print(data[:10])
            #print "PACKAGE RECEIVED..."
            f.write(data)
            if not data: break
```

this way f gets closed automatically when you leave the *with*  block when you exit the *while*.

I guess you need to extend the protocol so that the receiver knows what it gets and that you can let it act on that. Something like a 'begin-of-transfer' ... sending the filename, sending the data, sending 'end-of-transfer' that makes the receiver close the file

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code according to this and updated my post. But it still is not working for multiple photos.

Comment: No, and that is correct. The receiver needs to know exactly where the data ends for one file and starts for the other. Therefore you need to have a protocol so that they can understand eachother. That is not the case the way you set it up.

Comment: Using simple text markers like 'begin-of-transfer' & 'end-of-transfer' is not safe, since the data may contain the  'end-of-transfer' marker, although that's _extremely_ unlikely with JPEG data. But it's easy enough to get the file size...

Comment: Yeah, I got what you mean and now I'm wondering how can I do this. For example can I send a 1 or 0 bit at the end of each transmission. 1 indicating that there is another file is coming and after receiving that, receiver will create a new file and write the new data being sent from sender. And 0 indicating the sender has finished all its files. Is it possible or is there any better way to do so?

Comment: checkout existing protocols like *SMTP*, you can find details in the *smtplib.py* file.